# Is the behavior of a functor created by std::bind well-defined when the bound object expires?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, stdbind

Is the behavior of the following code well defined? How does the `f()` call behave?

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
  void shout()
  {
      std::cout <<"shout";
  }
};


int main()
{
    std::function<void()> f;
    {
        A a;
        f = std::bind(&A::shout, &a);
    }

    f();  // what happens here?
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code ends up storing a dangling reference (to an object that no longer exists) inside the function wrapper, and invoking the function results in undefined behaviour.

If the original object doesn't live as long as the wrapper, you can always store a *copy* of the object in the wrapper:

```
f = std::bind(&A::shout, a);
//                      ^^^ copy
```

Answer (score 2):

To show this is undefined, note that the address stored becomes an invalid pointer value - [[basic.stc]/3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0137r0.html):

> When the end of the duration of a region of storage is reached, the
>   values of all pointers representing the address of any part of the
>   deallocated storage become invalid pointer values ([basic.compound]).

In the call to the bound functor, that pointer is dereferenced to perform the member function call, where [[basic.stc.dynamic.deallocation]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc.dynamic.deallocation#4) applies:

> Indirection through an invalid pointer value and passing an invalid
>   pointer value to a deallocation function have undefined behavior.

Instead, you could bind `a` per value (omit the ampersand).

Comment: Also, calls to member functions require an object, [class.mfct.non-static]p1. Note that the code does not have UB AFAIK if `shout` is static. (There's an underlying question of *when*/*if* indirection happens.)

Comment: @dyp Edit: Whoops, I thought you referred to /2.

Comment: Is there a DR for p2?

Comment: @dyp The indirection happens, and that causes undefined behavior. We could have the same relaxation as with null pointers, where discarding the indirection's value is allowed, but that is not what's intended.

Comment: @dyp /2 is not defective in that it is inconsistent, but in that it should cover the case of an invalid lvalue being passed. (It's less of a defect than a need for clarification. /1 is not explicit enough about objects being required.)

Comment: There's a difference between indirecting through a null pointer and indirecting through an invalid(ated) pointer? That'd be weird...

Comment: @dyp Even given that indirection through a null pointer is covered in `typeid` expressions? We can practically see whether or not an lvalue is null, but it is not possible to distinguish between an invalid and valid lvalue (unless system support is used). And I don't see why sanitizers shouldn't be allowed to diagnose indirection of invalid pointer values.

Comment: I agree it's far from clear that an object is required, but it seems to have been enough for [CWG 315](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue315). I'm not sure if *indirection* is where the UB comes in, since [CWG 232](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue232) has not been resolved yet - therefore there doesn't seem to be a difference between an invalidated and a null pointer value, and for the latter, `a.shout()` is intended to work.

Comment: @dyp No, it's not. Calling a member function through a null pointer is UB; the 13 year old resolution of issue 315 is obsolete. (NB: There is a disincentive to allow this, but no incentives.) I don't understand what indirection you're referring to in your second sentence; indirection of null pointers is not per se undefined and I never disputed that, but that of invalid pointers has nothing to do with CWG 232.

Comment: For sanitizers, I think dynamic sanitizers won't see any indirection, and static sanitizers can see that the usage does not require the "value" of the pointer. `typeid` is a good point, but I think it's weird anyway because its operand is unevaluated only in some cases.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110896/discussion-between-dyp-and-columbo).